# Keep getting 0 as an output in C# division

Tags: c#, random, integer-division

I'm trying to divide a random number that is generated by 13. It can range from 1, 53. I need to divide the random number 13 to get a whole number (to determine what suit it is in a deck of cards). I need the suit to be out of 1-4.

Random number:

```
value = MyRandom.Next(1, 53);
```

Division:

```
suit = value / 13;
face = value % 13;
```

The suit keeps generating a 0 by the way.

Comment: what is `MyRandom`? And what debugger shows for `value` when you step through your code?

Comment: Is the `face` value also zero?

Comment: My random is just an object for the random number:

Comment: What whole number result would you expect from an integer division of 1 by 13? 1 / 13 = 0 always, when done as an integer division, so `suit` will always be 0 if `value < 13`.

Comment: heres a reference to c# '/' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx  
it should do exactly what is required here unless (1) value is not correct or (2) MyRandom.Next always gives the same number

Comment: The face value does not output zero

Comment: How do I make it so that when value < 13, it = 1?

Comment: you didn't divide the face value

Comment: Why 53 instead of 52? Is the extra card for the joker?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code before the call to MyRandom.Next? Where are you initializing MyRandom, what are you seeding it with?

Comment: You still haven't mentioned what `value` is - is it ever above 13?

@MichaelLiu 53 is one more than the maximum value, because `Next` will return at most one less than the max argument.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark as to what you're really asking.

I'm guessing you're actually getting non-zero values for `suit`, but you're also occasionally getting zero. The main issue here, in this case, ultimately boils down to 0-based vs 1-based indexing.

What you need to do is do all the generating/computing with 0-based indexing, and then add 1 to shift to 1-based indexing. (Alternatively, you could use 0-based indexing)

Example code:

```
value = MyRandom.Next(0, 52); // notice the values are inclusively between 0 and 51
suit = (value / 13) + 1; // this will be between 1 and 4
face = (value % 13) + 1; // this will be between 1 and 13
```

Comment: This is very similar what I was trying to say.  I must have failed horribly, since I've managed to garner -2 for a very similar answer.  Anyway, +1 since it's the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

To accomplish the task you are interested in, you should use a combination of casting your value to double and performing the [Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operator.

Your Suit code should be written as:

```
var suit = Math.Ceiling((double)value / 13);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `value / 13.0`

Comment: why the downvote? this is the correct algorithm with a link to the relevant method documentation

Answer (score -1):

It would be helpful if you posted a little more code. Random is not an easy thing for a computer to do because so much architecture goes into not doing random calculations. Therefore, the random generator in .net is a pseudorandom number sequence based off of a seed value. You can come up with your seed however you wish, but I've often seen the ticks of the current DateTime used. Here is an example using your problem and I got the expected outcome that you are looking for:

```
var rand = new Random((int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks % int.MaxValue));
var value = rand.Next(1, 53);
var suit = value / 13;
var face = value % 13;
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: The default constructor for Random uses the system clock to derive its seed, so seeding it yourself isn't usually necessary. The only reason you'd need to that I can think of is if you have to instantiate multiple ones in rapid sequence, which isn't the best practice on its own.

Comment: My bigger concern was that he was was instantiating a new Random each time through a loop and seeding with the same number. Since he didn't post code showing how he's creating his Random object, we won't know. Integer division and the mod operator should work regardless if his numbers are shifted by 1. Good catch on the default constructor.

Comment: Minor: Does not `% int.MaxValue` incorrectly prevent `Random()` from ever getting a seed of `int.MaxValue`?